# Use image instead of color for border in uiview or uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, border

I want to give border to my uiview and uiimageview but not diectly as cgcolor, i want to set some image as a border color is it possible in objective c.

Thanks[image: Image to be used as border ...]

Comment: can you upload the image which you want to set as border ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a color using the image you want to use:

```
UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"border.png"]];
view.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"image.png"]];`

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithPatternImage:)